# How can the following line be specified using `tput`

Tags: shell-script, colors, tput

How can the following line in Python, which adds colors to the text, be reproduced using `tput`?

```py
print('\x1b[1;34m::\x1b[0;1m Do you want to remove all other packages from cache? [Y/n] \x1b[0m')
```

I tried variants of `tput setaf 4`, `tput bold`, `tput sgr 0`, but can't quite get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An identical command to produce the same colors is:

```
$ echo "\n$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 4)::$(tput sgr0)$(tput bold) Do you want to remove all other packages from cache? [Y/n] $(tput sgr0)"
```

However any solution to output the identical escape codes as the question, with `tput` is very welcome.

Note that `$(tput sgr0)$(tput bold)` sets a white color that's not necessarily the same as `$(tput setaf 7)`.